# Can any plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ be described using a two vectors that only move on two axes?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let's say I have the plane $2x-y-z=11$, and when I want the parametric form I get $u_1=(1,2,0)$ & $u_2=(0,-2,1)$. Aren't all vectors spanning the same plane parallel to one of these vectors? I can't make sense of this because that would mean that there would be no vectors on the plane that move on all three axes. The issue I have is that it seems I can always get two vectors that only move on two axes, no matter the plane, but obviously not all planes are spanned by vectors that only move on two axes.

Comment: A plane is $ax+by+cz=d$ is "usually" two-dimensional, so you "expect" to have a basis of the subspace $ax+by+cz=0$ of cardinality $2$. Where is counterintuitive?

Comment: What do you mean by a vector which "moves on all three axes"?

Comment: I mean that in $\mathbb{R}^3$, a vector $u_3=(1,4,3)$ would move on all three axes since the values of $x$, $y$ and $z$ are all nonzero.

Comment: There are infinite many ways to parametrize a plane. The representation you get is probably due to the method to find one parametrization. But we cannot always find vectors with all components non-zero, namely if we have the xy, xz or yz-plane.

Comment: So it means "has a non-zero component along all three axes"? Your two vectors span the plane, but you can easily find two others spanning the same plane with 3 non-zero components e.g. (1, 1, -10) and (2, 1, -8). Other vectors in the plane are not parallel to these, but linear combinations of them.

Comment: Yes I realize the exact representation is unique. However, shouldn't all the vectors of the other representations be multiplies of the vectors that I get?

Comment: @Paul, no I mean that two of the three components are nonzero.

Comment: @Chisq In the normal form yes, but not in the parameter-form. Every pair of linear independent vectors having scalar product $0$ with the normal vector, spans the plane

Comment: @Peter So for two vectors to span the same plane as my vectors $u_1=(1,2,0)$ and $u_2=(0,-2,1)$ they do not have to be parallel to these vectors? If they do not, then my issue is solved.

Comment: No, you can have a completely different representation.

Comment: Huh, I see. I guess it was my understanding that was incorrect.

Comment: @Peter. Then what if I only exchange one of my vectors, does the one I replace it with have to be parallel to the one it replaced?

Comment: No, the remaining vector can have another direction.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One more question. Can it have any direction? Or is the set of directions it can have limited?

Comment: It must have sclar product $0$ with the normal vector and be linear independent to the first vector.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the example you have provided, assuming the standard basis $\left\{\mathbb{\hat{i}}, \mathbb{\hat{j}}, \mathbb{\hat{k}}\right\}$, the two vectors $u_1$ and $u_2$ have between them non-zero contributions in all components necessary to span the space.

In this manner, the plane cannot be contained solely within any one of the $xy$, $xz$ or $yz-$planes.

Hope this helps (and that I understood your question correctly).